# Skript not working arr.filter() in google apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is my script

```
    var arr1 = [[1],[2],[3],[4]],
        arr2 = [[2],[4]],
        res = arr1.filter( item => arr2.includes( item[0] ) );
    Logger.log(res);
```

And it doesn't work.
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using includes, you can use find, because you have arrays inside arrays.

```js
var arr1 = [[1], [2], [3], [4]],
  arr2 = [[2], [4]],
  res = arr1.filter((item) => arr2.find((el) => el[0] === item[0]));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Sorry. It's work!! Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that the all sub arrays of `arr2` contain just one element always, you can fix your code if you just add `.flat()` method in the second line:

```js
var arr1 = [[1],[2],[3],[4]],
    arr2 = [[2],[4]].flat(), // <-------------------------- here
    res = arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item[0]));

console.log(res);
```